# sample sequence of successive integer of an interval

Tags: r, random, sample

I have a question about sampling: I would like to sample successive number in a vector without replacement. Is there a simple way to do so? 
For example,

```
sample(c(1:100), 10, replace = F)
76 99 94 53 12 34  5 82 75 30
```

gives me 10 number between 1 and 100. Now I would like to have 10 sequence of 3 successive integer without replacement: `c(2,3,4), c(10,11,12), c(82,83,84)`  etc.

The different sequences can't overlap, that is if `c(2,3,4)` is my first sampling, then none of the following one can have these numbers.

I would even look for the possibility of sampling 10 sequences of different sizes, the sizes given by a vector like

```
sizevec <- sample(c(1:4),10,replace = T)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using tow `while` loop to take samples. After running the code, `x` is a list of desired output.

```
# Set seed for reproduciblility
set.seed(123)

# Create a list to store values
x <- list()
# Create a vector to store values in x
y <- integer()

# Set the threshold to stop
threshold <- 4

# Set the condition
condition <- TRUE

while (length(x) < threshold){
  while (condition){
    # Sample a number between 1 to 98
    s <- sample(c(1:98), 1)
    # Create a sequence
    se <- s:(s + 2)
    # Check if the values in se is in y, save it to the condition
    condition <- any(se %in% y) 
  }
  # Save se to the list
  x[[length(x) + 1]] <- se
  # Update y
  y <- unlist(x)
  # Reset the condition 
  condition <- TRUE
}

# View the results
x
# [[1]]
# [1] 29 30 31
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 79 80 81
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 41 42 43
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 89 90 91
```

Comment: Yes that will work. I didn't find better solution till now. Thanks for your help and time

Comment: @denis I decided to change `sample(c(1:100), 1)` to `sample(c(1:98), 1)` to make sure all values are between 1 to 100.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(42)
lapply(sample(1:10, 1) + cumsum(sample(4:10, 10, TRUE)), function(x) x + 1:3)
# [[1]]
# [1] 21 22 23

# [[2]]
# [1] 27 28 29

# [[3]]
# [1] 36 37 38

# [[4]]
# [1] 44 45 46

# [[5]]
# [1] 51 52 53

# [[6]]
# [1] 60 61 62

# [[7]]
# [1] 64 65 66

# [[8]]
# [1] 72 73 74

# [[9]]
# [1] 80 81 82

# [[10]]
# [1] 87 88 89
```

Answer (score 0):

HI you are unclear if the vectors may overlap or not. assuming the may overlap this should work

```
lapply(sample(c(1:97), 10, replace = F),function(i){ 0:2 + i})
```

having a random length would then look like this

```
lapply(sample(c(1:97), 10, replace = F),function(i){ 0:sample(1:10,1) + i})
```

Comment: Actually I would like them not to overlap. Sorry, I edited my question